# Can I make one view in my app appear in Landscape and all others in portrait mode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

My iPhone app is all in portrait mode at the moment.

But I need to play a video that in widescreen mode and draw some ui elements that work best in portrait mode. Also there will be some text input in the screen at times, so keyboard will need to appear as portrait too.

Is it possible to tell a UIViewController when it loads that it needs to go to Landscape, the parent view on the stack will be Portrait.

I dont want to detect the user rotating, I want to decide which screens will be landscape and which will be portrait.

So to recap, everyscreen/view on my app will be portrait, except one that I would like to make Landscape. Can it be done?

Many Thanks,
-Code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your UIViewController you implement this method

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
// Return YES for supported orientations
BOOL result = NO;
if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || 
             interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
    result = YES;
}
return result;
}
```

And you return `YES` for the orientation you want to support.
This method will be call on your UIViewController when it load, so it won't get call every time you enter in that UIViewController.

---

And if you want to be absolutely certain that all other UIViewController are the orientation you want, implement this method in them as well.

Comment: I would suggest using something slightly simpler like `return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);` or simply putting `return TRUE` inside the if and putting an else after.  It's the same code, just compressed a bit and no need to make a variable here.

Comment: @WolfLink I agree for the first part, but I hate return that are not early return for failure.  But anyway, I've construct the code like this here for pedagogical reason, to show very clearly the option you need to take and if it's passing the test that mean you want to return YES, else NO.  But like you said, if the `if` evaluate to YES or NO, why not return that result directly, just like in the Apple template.

Comment: you can simply ```return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);```

Answer (score 1):

Yup, use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight]];` or portrait for portrait orientation.

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeRight.rawValue
    UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarHidden = true
}


override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

and change it to what you want (LandscapeRight , LandscapeLeft or Portrait)